# How to put AJAX-results in the right DIV with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a Javascript file which retrieves information from a MySQL-server. This script looks up three different text-scripts from the database. The problem is that only the result of the latest is presented. I want the three text parts in three different DIV's.
Now the results are presented 3 times the same:
Here is the code:

```
     ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    //var nummer = document.getElementById('nummer').value;

    var queryString1 = "?nummer1=" + nummer1;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-comm1.php" + queryString1, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

    var queryString2 = "?nummer2=" + nummer2;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-comm2.php" + queryString2, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

    var queryString3 = "?nummer3=" + nummer3;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-comm3.php" + queryString3, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

The DIV's are:

```
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to show your code in which you are manipulating the results of those AJAX requests. Where are your success callbacks? Where did you subscribe to the `onreadystatechange` event?

Comment: Hi Darin. I added the onreadystatechange code to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your calls into three distinct XmlHTTPRequest objects. Your one-stop `onreadystatechange` will overwrite any previous usage and set every div to the same value. It's now a race to see which AJAX request finishes last.

```
function updateDiv(number, divID) {
  var queryString = '?number' + number + '=' + number;
  var div = document.getElementById(divID);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', 'ajax-comm' + number + '.php' + queryString, true);
  xhr.send();
  return xhr;
}

updateDiv(1, 'result1');
updateDiv(2, 'result2');
updateDiv(3, 'result3');
```

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nonaz/1/edit) that illistrates this.

Comment: I've tried to do so. The only difference in the result is that the text of the third item is not displayed anymore at number 1 and 2. But when I look into my network editor (I am not allowed to add pictures) than nr 1 and 2 have the status 'cancelled' and has status '200 ok'.

Comment: Well, I didn't see your example at first. My editor has some problems with the dot in:   'var xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {'. Is that ok or a mistype?

Comment: I've changed the code a little bit to avoid confusion about the Dutch nummer and the English number variables and added a for next loop for the variable nummer1,2 and 3. Otherwise it didn't work. But the foundation has been made by this solution, so Sukima, many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery try -

```
   $( "#result1" ).load( "ajax-comm2.php"+ queryString1 );
   $( "#result2" ).load( "ajax-comm2.php"+ queryString2 );
   $( "#result3" ).load( "ajax-comm2.php"+ queryString3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. I am looking for a kind of  reference like "#result1" etc, but is it possible in Javascript as well?

Comment: Try  document.getElementById("result"+i) as mentioned by chandu.

Comment: @BhabaniMishra, no, that won't help at all. The correct way to achieve this is to have 3 separate instances of the XmlHttpRequest object which is what Sukima suggested in his answer but didn't provide a code example.

Answer (score 0):

please change your if condition according to this

```
if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
              for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
                document.getElementById("result"+i).innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
         }
```

Comment: What if the third AJAX request completes before the first one? Your code would simply overwrite all divs with the response of the current AJAX request completed which is not what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: In that case, do one thing send the div ids from back end and append the value to the div

Comment: Why waste bandwidth for that when you can achieve the desired result purely client side as Sukima suggested by using separate XmlHttpRequest instances? Also from the server perspective it makes strictly no sense to be sending client side ids when they will not be used at all by the server side, only to echo them back to the client - a complete waste.

Comment: @user3107597, look at Sukima's answer if you are looking for the correct way to achieve that.